# How to get textarea in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html table is under code

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <a href="#this" class="btn" id="edit">edit</a>
         </th>
     </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <textarea></textarea>
        </td>
     </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How to get textarea in `#edit` button click event?

```
$(function() {
    $("#edit.btn").click(function() {

    });
});
```

I trying:

```
$(this).closest('tbody tr th textarea')
```

It's not working.

How can I get the `textarea` in button click event?

Comment: Why not just give the textarea an ID; by far the easiest.

Comment: anyway `$(this).closest('table').find('textarea')`

Comment: @adeneo thank it work

Comment: That's not valid HTML markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get to the first common ancestor your button (`#edit`) has with the target element (the `textarea`). You can do this like so:

```
$("#edit.btn").click(function() {
  var $textarea = $(this).closest('table').find('textarea');
});
```

Alternatively you can give the `textarea` an identifier (say... `'id'` attribute?), and target it directly like so:

```
$("#edit.btn").click(function() {
  var $textarea = $('#your-textarea-id');
});
```

Finally, if this is a dynamic code, and you have multiple pairs of `button` & `textarea`, you can put the `textarea`'s identifier on you `button` element like so:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#this" class="btn" id="edit" data-target="my-text-0">edit</a>
...
...
...
<textarea id="my-text-0"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$("#edit.btn").click(function() {
  var $textarea = $('#'+$(this).data('target'));
});
```